# Feedme plugin - importing users into craft commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-feedme

I have few questions about importing users into Craft CMS using feedme. These users would be also Craft Commerce customers.

- Users will be imported without passwords. Would this provide some kind of security risk, for example, someone being able to log in with empty password?
- Setting new passwords for users - would I need to write custom module to send password reset form to each imported user? Would not sending 5000 emails at once choke Craft - maybe I should use tasks for that?
- Addresses - do i need to write some custom plugin for importing adddress data along with basic user data like email? I didnt saw any fields for setting up user address when i tested importing users using feedme. Did someone managed to tackle this issue in the past?

Comment: I have a problem with Feed Me. when i added the URL's of File in Feed URL, I can't connect the Data and I can't see the Change. what is the Problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Users will be imported without passwords. Would this provide some kind of security risk, for example, someone being able to log in with empty password?

I don't think the imported users will be able to login at all without a password.

> Setting new passwords for users - would I need to write custom module to send password reset form to each imported user? Would not sending 5000 emails at once choke Craft - maybe I should use tasks for that?

I handled this by setting a message on the login and forgot password pages, skipping the need to send an email. Something like "Our systems were upgraded on 10-20-2020, if you've not logged in since then you'll need to reset your password first".

> Addresses - do i need to write some custom plugin for importing adddress data along with basic user data like email? I didnt saw any fields for setting up user address when i tested importing users using feedme. Did someone managed to tackle this issue in the past?

Yes, you will need to use a custom module/plugin and listen to feedme events and handle address import with your code.

Something like:

```
 Event::on(Process::class, Process::EVENT_STEP_AFTER_ELEMENT_SAVE, function (FeedProcessEvent $event) {
   /// your code here dealing with $event->feedData;         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to import user data from Prestashop into Craft Commerce v4 and came up with this solution, which uses a Yii module.

```
// Create address elements from feed-me import
Event::on(
    Process::class, 
    Process::EVENT_STEP_AFTER_ELEMENT_SAVE, 
    function(FeedProcessEvent $event) {
        $addressElement = $this->_createAddress($event->contentData, $event->element->id);
});
```

I then adapted a function I found in the UpdateController in Commerce 4 that is used to update existing Commerce 3 installations:

```
private function _createAddress($data, $id): Address
    {

        $address = new Address();
        $address->title = 'Meine Adresse';

        // set the owner (user) of the address element
        if (isset($id)) {
            $address->ownerId = $id;
        }

        $address->addressLine1 = $data['addressline1'];
        if (isset($data['addressline2'])) {
            $address->addressLine2 = $data['addressline2'];
        }

        $address->countryCode = 19;

        switch ($data['countryid']) {
            case '19':
                $address->countryCode = 'CH';
                break;
            case '1':
                $address->countryCode = 'DE';
                break;
            case '2':
                $address->countryCode = 'FR';
                break;
            case '130':
                $address->countryCode = 'LI';
                break;
            case '10':
                $address->countryCode = 'IT';
                break;
        }

        $address->administrativeArea = null;

        $address->postalCode = $data['postalcode'];
        $address->locality = $data['city'];
        $address->dependentLocality = '';

        if ($data['firstname'] || $data['lastname']) {
            $address->fullName = implode(' ', array_filter([$data['firstname'], $data['lastname']]));
        }

        if (isset($data['company'])) {
            $address->organization = $data['company'];
        }

        $address->dateCreated = DateTimeHelper::toDateTime($data['dateupdate']);
        $address->dateUpdated = DateTimeHelper::toDateTime($data['postalcode']);
        Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($address, false, false, false);

        return $address;
    }
```

You might not need all the code in this function but you will get the idea.